# Can not attach policy for existing user with CDK

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I can not figure it out why I am getting error "Cannot add inline policy to imported User"

Background: I have an existing user that I get from:

`const testUser = iam.User.fromUserName(this,'test','alarm_test')`

Then I create policy with statement and attach policy to the user:

```
    policy.addStatements( new iam.PolicyStatement({   
        effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        resources: [
          '*'
        ],
        actions: [
          "ec2:DescribeInstances"
        ]            
      }));

    policy.attachToUser(testUser);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the aws-cdk source code [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/957f04790524cedf2cea2de08988e24783a2eca6/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/user.ts), it looks like you can't add any policies to imported users, and there isn't any good documentation as to why.

I don't have a workaround, but I'd recommend creating a feature request on the AWS Github page, the devs may be able to give you more insight as to why.

Comment: It can be added to a role with no problem using method attachToRole. At least it implies it should work for the attachToUser.

Answer (score 0):

source code here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/d5918c330b6770b84efc5417ce1109a68c22119b/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/user.ts#L161

I think the reason is because it's generally considered a bad practice to attach inline policies to a user.

Comment: It is true managed policies is the recommended way, however, in case there is a need for inline policy there should be a way which I believe found. When I get a chance I will double check and if I have it in code I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

This should no longer be a problem as it is fixed in newer versions. But for people like me who work with older versions, there is a workaround that worked for me.

Create an IAM group, add the (managed) policy you want and add the user to that group. It's a bit tedious, but should work.